# Codeigniter Message: Undefined variable: data

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy aprendiendo a levantar una vista y traer datos
no entiendo donde me falta declarar la variable
si me ayudan gracias

vista :

```
<h1> Aprendiendo a levantar una vista </h1> <?php var_dump($data);?>
```

controlador:

```
    class Proyectoema extends CI_Controller
{
    protected $CI;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();

         $this->load->model('proyectoema/Proyectoema_model');
       
        
    }
    public function index()
    {

            $data = $this->Proyectoema_model->get_libros();
      
            $this->load->view('layouts/adminLTE');
            $this->load->view('proyectoema/emanuel',$data);
        
            //$this->load->view('layouts/footer');
        
        

    }


}
```

Modelo:

```
    class Proyectoema_model extends BaseModel
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->db_gestion = $this->load->database('biblioteca', TRUE);
            
            
        }
    
        public function get_libros(){
    
            $this->db_gestion->select('*');
            $this->db_gestion->from('libros');
    
            $query = $this->db_gestion->get();
            return $query->result_array();
    
        }
    
    }
```

y este es el error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: data
>
> Filename: proyectoema/emanuel.php
>
> Line Number: 80
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\BackednColombia\application\views\proyectoema\emanuel.php
> Line: 80 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\BackednColombia\application\controllers\proyectoema\Proyectoema.php
> Line: 21 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\BackednColombia\index.php Line: 315 Function:
> require_once

Comment: tambien tengo la ruta $route['proyectoema/(:any)']['GET'] = 'proyectoema/Proyectoema/index/$1';

Comment: ¿Pero tienes declarada la variable `$data`? Lo normal sería declararla en el controlador extendido `Proyectoema`, ¿no?

Comment: h1> Aprendiendo a levantar una vista </h1>
<?php 

 $data = $this->Proyectoema_model->get_libros();
 var_dump($data);
 

?>

Comment: de esta manera me muestra el array , pero pense que con declararla en el controlador ya estaba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se debe a que no estas pasando correctamente los datos a la vista desde el controlador.

Si en la vista queres obtener una variable `$data`, entonces, en el controlador necesitas enviar los datos así:

```php
//           ↓ clave usada para dar nombre a la variable en la vista
$params = ['data' => $this->Proyectoema_model->get_libros()];
$this->load->view('proyectoema/emanuel', $params);
```

---

Más info:

- [CodeIgniter > View > Adding Dynamic Data to the View](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view)

Comment: excelente muchas gracias